# Primary SSL re-routing HTTP add-on

Tags: ssl, subdomain, mixed-content

As a complete newbie, I've been skulking through this site for about the past twelve months to find solutions to errors. The following issue has driven me to distraction to such a degree that I decided to join the fun and see if anyone can help.

I have a main site which has an essential SSL certificate. I recently created another site as an add-on domain to the main hosting. However, this means the add-on tries to run as https, causing a security error and blocking most of the html and css document. I'd be very grateful if anyone could offer advice on how to work around this.

Comment: under `add-on domain` you mean a subdomain?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates are valid only for the domain specificed in the CN.

However you are not only one with this requirement, so what you can do:

- use a [wildcard certificate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) - the wildcard certificates are usually more expensive, but they cover all subdomain on that level (*.domain.com covers www.domain.com, mail.domain.com, ... but not domain.com itself)
- use [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) - it is an explicit list of domiains covered by the certificate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the WIldcard option, however only my primary domain requires an SSL cert. so this would be quite a waste of money, especially as there must be some way of re-directing.

Comment: then maybe `Subject Alternative Names` could be viable option. or you could use pure http while not mixing content. though if you care about security or rating, ssl is the way to go